# How can I prevent an external JS file from breaking my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixpanel

I'm currently using Mixpanel on my site. For some reasons they go down from time to time and that disables my site from loading.

Is there a way I can make the load async or some other idea where it doesn't bring down my site when they have downtime?

Here's the code:

```
<script>
    var mp_protocol = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + mp_protocol + "api.mixpanel.com/site_media/js/api/mixpanel.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "bring down your site"? It's not like jquery, how come it affects your website functioning?

Comment: @Rufus, If the external domain is down/slow, if causes the page to hang up and wait for that resource. You see it all the time browsing the ad with some crappy ad services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not document.write it to the page, append it.

```
<script>
$( function(){
    var mp_protocol = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
    jQuery.getScript(unescape(mp_protocol + "api.mixpanel.com/site_media/js/api/mixpanel.js"));
});
</script>
```

Comment: And put the '<script>' tag in the bottom of '<body>' will help improve user experience. eg, '<body>blablabla<script></script></body>'